# From where/how the files get populated in /var/www/html?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am learning Docker and trying to understand `volumes`.   Looking at this example of [wordpress compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/#define-the-project) and its [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/7902c5f856c7fbc20dd70762bef324158328dcff/php5.6/apache/Dockerfile) I don't get which command is responsible for populating wordpress files into `/var/www/html`.

I do see that there is `VOLUME /var/www/html` command in the dockerfile to create a mount point.

There is command to download wordpress files and put in `/usr/src/wordpress` directory.

But what I don't get is how does files get into `/var/www/html`?

Is it just that mounting to this directory cause all the wordpress files magically stored in this?

Is it somewhere else docker is doing this?

**EDIT:** These wordpress files are already moved or copied when ran `docker-compose up`. I'm not asking how can move/mount files into `/var/www/html`. But question is how this things happened referring to the dockerfile and docker compose file above.

Thanks

Comment: Hey can you help with solution? How to stop filling var/www?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the `entrypoint` is copying the files if they don't already exist. Note in the Dockerfile that [the wordpress source is added to /usr/src/wordpress](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/7902c5f856c7fbc20dd70762bef324158328dcff/php5.6/apache/Dockerfile#L41). Then, when the container starts, the entrypoint [checks if some files exist](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/7902c5f856c7fbc20dd70762bef324158328dcff/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L27) and if they don't, it [copies the wordpress source into the current directory](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/7902c5f856c7fbc20dd70762bef324158328dcff/php5.6/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L33), which is `WORKDIR`, which is /var/www/html.

### General Docker Volume Stuff

With `/var/www/html` specified as a `VOLUME`, the only way to get files into there from the container's perspective is to attach a docker volume with files to that. Think of it as a mountpoint.

You can either attach a local filesystem to that volume:

```
docker run -v /path/to/local/webroot:/var/www/html wordpress
```

or you can create a docker volume and use it for a persistent, more docker-esque object:

```
docker volume create webroot
```

And then move the files into it with a transient container:

```
docker run --rm -v /path/to/local/webroot:/var/www/html \
           -v webroot:/var/www/html2 \
           ubuntu cp -a /var/www/html/ /var/www/html2
```

at which point you have `webroot` as a docker volume you can attach to any container.

```
docker run -v webroot:/var/www/html wordpress
```

Comment: If i understand correctly , you are telling me how I can and move or mount files into `/var/www/html` right ?  If i'm right then may be you misunderstood me. Wordpress files are already moved/copied into `/var/www/html` when i did `docker-compose up`. So my question is how that happened? :S And I don't see any files attached command to that volume in `dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Right you are. Edited.